# Push array list in mongoose in one call

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use promise and Mongoose,
I wanna to push array in array.

Array schema and function:

```
Temp: [{
        code: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
        }
    }],


 var arr =[2525,2525, 2525, 2525]

        Room.where({ _id: new ObjectID(_RoomID) }).updateOne({ $addToSet: { Temp: { code: arr } } }).then(() => {
         }, () => {

      })
```

I used this code but not working with arr,
if i set a single var number ex : 
var arr=2525 
everything is correct and stored

How can i do this with array list ???

UPDATE:

My problem has been resolved.  I used This Code:

```
   var arr = []

    for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
         var obj = {};   
         obj['code'] = 2525;
         arr.push(obj); 
    }

    Room.where({ _id: new ObjectID(_RoomID) }).updateOne({ $push: { Temp: { $each: arr } } }).then(() => {

       }, () => {
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Check `$push` and `$each` from MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#example-push-each). Example:

```
db.students.update(
   { name: "joe" },
   { $push: { scores: { $each: [ 90, 92, 85 ] } } }
)
```